# How to create a Sengrid Subscription with Terraform in Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, terraform, twilio, sendgrid, azure-marketplace

I want to create a Sendgrid Subscription with Terraform from the Azure Marketplace.
Currently i have to use the UI, but it would be nice to create the Subscription and automatically retreive an access token for Sendgrid in Terraform.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Terraform (TF), but you can provision SendGrid using Azure Resource Management (ARM) templates. And you can deploy ARM templates through TF, so indirectly, you should be able to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I tried and researched couple days ago, there's no way for us to create the Sendgrid anymore.
Since it's migrated to be SaaS in Azure, the platform does not support for automation by ARM or Terraform, even Biceps.
You possible look into this thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/559161/sendgrid-as-saas-resource-arm-template-deployment.html
But the platform also disabled the Deployment template generation (right after creation and resource export too).
And many others function are also disabled (change resource group, manage account on Portal, .etc).
So this problem also frustrated me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have researched and still not found any solution to automate the process. Just create the SendGrid Saas manuelly, and try to export it as ARM template. The Azure can't export it and displays the error   "The schema of resource type 'Microsoft.SaaS/resources' is not available. Resources of this type will not be exported to the template"